# Testing React-Router v1.0.0 href

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Currently using Jest with React-Router to try and test an element has an href with the expected value.

from following the instructions [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/testing.md)

```
jest.dontMock('../BasicPage')

describe('BasicPage', function() {
  let BasicPage = require('../BasicPage')
  let TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils')
  let ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
  let React = require('react')

  it('renders the Login button if not logged in', function() {
    let page = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<BasicPage />)
    let button = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(page, 'button')
    expect(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(button).textContent).toBe('Login')
  })

  it('renders the Account button if logged in', function() {
    let page = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<BasicPage authenticated={true} />)
    let button = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(page, 'button')
expect(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(button).getAttribute('href')).toBe('/admin')
  })
})
```

the element has a link like:

```
<Button bsStyle="primary"><Link to="/admin">Login</Link></Button>
```

when console.log'in the button the href isn't present and the test return null!

Has anyone found a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to render things under a `<Router>` instance if you want e.g. `<Link>`s to actually work. The `<Router>` provides the history instance on context that `<Link>` uses to generate `href`s and handle clicks.

For convenience in testing, we will let you render `<Link>`s without a history instance, but as you can see, they won't be functional.

Comment: would you do this after importing react-router?
    <Router>
        <BasicPage />
    </Router

Answer (score -1):

`expect(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(button).getAttribute('href')).toBe('/admin')`

Isn't that finding the wrong thing? don't you want to find the anchor?

Comment: @JimmyJia was right to be able to see the href attribute you need to wrap your element in a <router> -> <route> -> <component>.

This is useful for some user cases when url's are being processed via a function on componentDidMount.
But as you mentioned in tweet our user case is to check links display right component as we are trying to replace integration tests. Would you say moving it to unit test is a wise choice?